# Sorting almost ordered sequence

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I have a sequence, which can be really long.

I am inputing the number of elements and the special number, which will cut my sequence into the parts, for example:

```
 10 2
```

here I have 10 numbers and 5 blocks (10/2)

I must sort this sequence using merge sort

here is the code:

```
  int number_of_elements, k;

  cin >> number_of_elements;
  cin >> k;
  int* massiv_1 = new int[k];
int* massiv_2 = new int[k];
int* resulted_massiv = new int[number_of_elements];

for(int i = 0; i < number_of_elements; i++) {
    resulted_massiv[i] = 0;
}

int i = 0;

while( i < number_of_elements) {

    int counter_1 = 0;
    int counter_2 = 0;

    cin >> massiv_1[counter_1];
    counter_1++;

    if( i != 0 ) {
        quick_Sort( massiv_1, k-1 );

        for(; counter_2 < k; counter_2++) {
            cin >> massiv_2[counter_2];
            counter_2++;
        }

        quick_Sort( massiv_2, k-1 );

        merge(massiv_1, k, massiv_2, k, resulted_massiv, i);
    }

    counter_1 = 0;
    counter_2 = 0;

    i = i + k;
}
```

here is the merge sort

```
 void merge(int *a, int a_len, int *b, int b_len, int *c, int z1) {

int i = 0, j = 0;
for(;i < a_len && j < b_len;) {
    if(a[i] < b[j]) {
        c[z1] = a[i];
        ++i;
    } else  {
        c[z1] = b[j];
        j++;
    }
}
if(i == a_len) {
    for(; j < b_len; ++j) {
        c[z1] = b[j];
    }
} else {
    for(; i < a_len; ++i) {
        c[z1] = a[i];
    } 
}
```

}

In other words here is the algorithm:

First I cut sequnce into k parts

I am going through it, if I see the index = k, I am using quick_sort,

then I go to the nearest block and also use quick_sort,

and then I am using merge sorting puting it into other array

...and this I am doing till the end of the sequence

this algorithm doesn't work, if enter this:

```
    10 4
    0 4 3 2 1 8 7 6 5 9
```

it must sort this sequence, but it shows this:

```
    0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 8 0
```

I can't get it

I will really appreciate your help, thank you in advance!!!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I have edited

Comment: Pancake sorting is perfect for sorting almost sorted sequence, or in other words a sequence of sorted subsequences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always write in single **c[z1]** element in merge function, and never increment z1 index.
Index in "c" array should be incremented at every step, so you can use `c[z1++]` everywhere in the funcion

Comment: merge(massiv_1, k, massiv_2, k, resulted_massiv, i); here I increment the z1, or it is not right?

Comment: No, you define starting point of resulted array, but write all values in this point only. See edit.

Comment: I have changed the code, as you had told me, but I still had a problem, I got this: -842150451 -842150451 -842150451 1 3 4 7 8 0 0... couldn't you explain me why does it happen? thank you for your answer!

Comment: I think you have to check algorithm thoroughly and the program, tracking function parameters (arrays' ranges)